# PostgreSQL SQL Problem with Triggers and duplicates

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I have a problem and i want to eliminate non-relevant information using a SQL query and triggers

Table is

```
create table z_test(id, fyear smallint, byear text);
```

data to be inserted .

```
insert into z_test  (fyear, byear) values (Null, '2018 2019 2020');
insert into z_test  (fyear, byear) values (null, '2018 2019 2020');
insert into z_test  (fyear, byear) values (null,  '2018 2019 2020');
```

problem definition: I want fyear to be 2018 for the first row, 2019 for the second row and
2020 for the third row. If the number of rows i am inserting is equal to the number of years
in byear, it should be inserted. If it is not equal, then its ok to insert Null into fyear

Alternatively, i could also get data like this.

```
insert into z_test  (fyear, byear) values (Null, '2018 2019 ');
insert into z_test  (fyear, byear) values (null, '2018 2019 ');
```

In this case, 2018 should be first row and 2019 the second row.

What i have tried so far. Tried to create a CTE in a trigger that inserts into z_test. Inside
the trigger, i use regexp_split_to_table to split the byear into rows. I then try to put the first
year in the first row, second year in the second row and so on. I am using transactions and psycopg2. Unfortunately, the problem is the trigger is not able to find previously uncommitted rows in the table and i am stuck here. Please help. So all values are going as null. Is there a way to do it with an SQL Query, preferably triggers?

```
CREATE TRIGGER z_test_trigger
    AFTER INSERT
    ON public.z_test
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.z_test_procedure();

CREATE FUNCTION public.z_test_procedure()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF
AS $BODY$
BEGIN 
    
        WITH cte AS(
        select numyr::SMALLINT,byear from 
        (select  trim(regexp_split_to_table(NEW.ner_text, '\s+')) AS numyr 
         )x where is_numeric(numyr) =true and length(numyr)=4 and numyr like '20%' )
        SELECT numyr INTO NEW.fyear FROM cte  WHERE numyr NOT IN (SELECT byear FROM z_test WHERE  
         NEW.byear =  cte.byear  ) LIMIT 1  ;
    
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$;
```

Comment: The solution would be to clean the data before the `INSERT`. A function runs in its own transaction it will not see uncommitted information in other transactions as you have found out.

Comment: It is part of a single transaction. I insert rows into the table as part of a single transaction. I can ignore other transactions i am not inserting as it would be an entirely different process. My question is, why is the trigger not "seeing" data i previously inserted even though it is the same transaction? Postgre Documentation" Read Committed is the default isolation level in PostgreSQL. ...However, SELECT does see the effects of previous updates executed within its own transaction, even though they are not yet committed. "

Comment: Well for starters  it is an `AFTER TRIGGER`, so `RETURN NEW;` has no effect. See [plpgsql trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html).

Answer (score 0):

I have absolutely no idea what you mean by *"if the number of rows i am inserting is equal to the number of years in byear, it should be inserted. If it is not equal, then its ok to insert Null into fyear"* It seems to imply your trigger has to remember how may Inserts statements have been processed. It cannot; so the whole thing is meaningless - unless you can explain.  
At any rate a trigger implementation is the wrong way to go. Instead of multiple inserts to generate several rows you can do this with a single insert statement and get rid of the trigger altogether. Use a CTE to break out values from `byear` then *Insert ... select..* for each value in the CTE (and you can handle duplicates at the same time):

```
alter table z_test add constraint fyear_uk unique(fyear);

with cte (fyear, byear) as  
     ( select  trim(regexp_split_to_table('2018 2019 2020', '\s+')), '2018 2019 2020')
insert into z_testfyear, byear)
     select cte.fyear::smallint, cte.byear 
       from cte 
      where cte.fyear ~ '^20\d\d$'
 on conflict (fyear) do nothing;
```

To avoid duplication the `byear` string you can wrap the query in an SQL Procedure with a parameter for the `byear` value.

```
create or replace 
procedure generate_z_test(byear_in text)
  language sql
as $$
     with cte (fyear, byear) as  
          ( select trim(regexp_split_to_table(byear_in, '\s+')), byear_in )
     insert into z_test(fyear, byear)
          select cte.fyear::smallint, cte.byear 
            from cte 
           where cte.fyear ~ '^20\d\d$' 
     on conflict (fyear) do nothing;
$$;
```

See [demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=fe84b386ceccd5b79620a4d648e79e4a).